# State is updated in console but not added to screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still a bit new to React and JavaScript. I'm trying to create a Daily Wins app, where the user can add an entry. I am able to create a new entry, and when I console log, the state is updated for the new entry, but the data is not rendered on screen. The code is viewable on this codebox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mindfulness-codesandbox-fe7ys?file=/src/components/DailyWinsComponent.js:1076-1197

Sorry if this may be a really common question (this is my first Q here)!

[Empty new entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORqEh.png)
[Console log with updated state for that empty new entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPgfR.png)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You miss matching key in submit function. so current object is not match. need to separate object in your submit function:

```
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!currentEntry.date) {
      alert("Please add your entry");
      return;
    }
    onAdd({...currentEntry }); //change here

    setCurrentEntry(initialEntryValue);
  };
```

Comment: @miss_indecisive you're welcome. i'm glad if you accept my answers